# play/pause button won't play audio, it is working more as a play/stop button instead

Tags: javascript

So currently when I press the button the audio plays and pauses but the audio doesn't continue playing from the point where it was last paused. Might have to do with the once function but I'm just stuck on this, as im fairly new and currently trying to learn javascript.

```
if (document.body.addEventListener) {
    document.body.addEventListener('click', yourHandler, false);
}else {
    document.body.attachEvent('onclick', yourHandler);//for IE
}

//yourHandler();
function once(fn, context) {
    var result;
    return function () {
        if (fn) {
            result = fn.apply(context || this, arguments);
            fn = null;
        } return result;
    };
}

// Usage
function canOnlyFireOnce(target) {
    console.log('Fired!');
    if (target) {
        audio.src = target.id;
    }
}

window.audio = new Audio();
audio.className = "ppbtn";
audio.autoplay = false;

function yourHandler(e) {
    window.e = e || window.event;
    window.target = e.target || e.srcElement;

    qElem = document.querySelector(".elemnts");

    canOnlyFireOnce(target);
    console.log(audio.src);

    if (target.className.match(/ppbtn/)) {
        console.log(audio.src);
        let listOfButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".ppbtn");
    for (let i = 0; i < listOfButtons.length; i++) {
        if (listOfButtons[i].id != target.id) {
            listOfButtons[i].textContent = "play";
        }
    }
    if (target.textContent == "play") {
        audio.play();
        target.textContent = "pause";
    }
    else {
        audio.pause();
        target.textContent = "play";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I may, `attachEvent` is for IE **< 9** and there was no `Audio` at that time. Oh and I missed this code is even using `let` afterward, your IE support just dropped to Edge+

Comment: @Kaiido does this address the question in any way? Even though you're right, this is not related to the topic and probably isn't even an issue for him.

Comment: @JanisJansen so? Isn't it a fair use of the comments? From the "add a comment" link's title: "*Use comments to ask for more information **or suggest improvements.***". Not having all these useless parts in the code would make for a clearer question.

Comment: @Kaiido It is. I just doubt the helpfulness for a developer trying to learn javascript.

Comment: IMM that would be easier for them to learn if they don't try to make their code work with IE6, even at the time it was in use it was already a pain to deal with. Better for them to learn with the minimal required today.

Answer (score 2):

You are re-setting the `src` of your Audio. This will cause the `currentTime` to be reset too.

```
function canOnlyFireOnce(target) {
    console.log('Fired!');
    if (target) {
        audio.src = target.id; // <-- This is bad
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a reason to do so, so just don't.

Comment: this is helpful but how do I have it so the src is only set once? also I created multiple buttons using DOM and have multiple audio files, so I don't think I can just set the source individually.

Comment: The excerpt of your code I posted contains a comment pointing out what you need to remove.